# LESS CSS - Single template, multiple settings, compile to multiple CSS

Tags: html, css, templates, less

Is it possible to generate multiple CSS files from a single LESS template and multiple LESS settings files?

For example, I have these files

`template.less
template.settings1.less
template.settings2.less
template.settings3.less`

I know that I can import each settings file into the template file, but to my knowledge the only way to get the three files is to duplicate the template file three times. Is there a way to use the `template.less` only once and generate three CSS files from it based on the settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, nevermind. I'm a fool.

You can achieve this by creating a new LESS file (for example, "myTemplate.type1.less") and doing the following for each type of "template" you wish:

`@import "template.settings1.less";
@import "template.less";`

And that's it!